# How to know how long your website took to render in a browser?

Tags: javascript, browser

Is there a way to know how long your website took to download on a client? (when you don't own the browser), preferably a simple vanilla javascript script would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```js
var now = new Date().getTime();
        var page_load_time = now - performance.timing.navigationStart;
        $("#labletest").text("Page render time is : " + page_load_time + " ms")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span><label id="labletest"></label></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use tools like [Pingdom](https://tools.pingdom.com/) and [GTMetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Access logs give you some hints. You can look for the begin of the first request and the begin of the last request for loading a page.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a new browser, which has`window.performance`, you can do timing on many things.

Follow the specs here: https://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/#sec-window.performance-attribute

In your specific case, I think what you want is:

 `window.performance.timing.domInteractive - window.performance.timing.navigationStart`

That will give you the time frome when user hits enter in the url, to when the dom is interactive (not completely loaded, but user can interact with the page, like click a link, or select text).

(image from https://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/#sec-window.performance-attribute)

[image]